# MongoDb aggregation 16MB buffer size limit

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to run mongo db aggregate query from c#, but buffer size is exceeding 16MB. Is there any way to adjust the buffer size or any other workaround. I do not have the option to create collection in mongo server side and also I do not have any mongo utility like mongo.exe or mongoExport.exe in my client system.

Comment: Not really. A document in MongoDB is limited to 16MB and messages are documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set AllowDiskUse and OutputMode in AggregateArgs to allow more than 16 MB.

```
 var mongoPipeline = new AggregateArgs { Pipeline = pipeline, AllowDiskUse = true, OutputMode = AggregateOutputMode.Cursor };
 var response = Repository.Collection.Aggregate(mongoPipeline)
```

See [MongoDB Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/) for more informations.

Comment: If my answer helped you solving your problem, please vote it up and mark it as "answer".